# Community-created dungeons for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Just finished playing the Pathfinder Beginner Box Set adventure with my sons (as a first experience for us, and it was great fun). It would be fun to continue this, but building a whole dungeon after one go at this is a bit overwhelming.

Just wondering if there is an online community for this series that shares user-created dungeons?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: @watt, I have an answer that may be useful, but it technically doesn't answer the question you've asked. Is it important that you find community made resources, or are you just looking for free adventures you can use? If you want to add "or other free" to your question, I've already written an answer with links, but realized I technically am answering a different question than you've asked.

Comment: Hello - yeswe would also be looking for "other free" resources as well as community made resources / dungeons.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind giving up control, or even being separated, you can play online with other people on websites like [roll20](https://app.roll20.net/home).

However, if that is not really something you want to do, you can use go to [Dyson's Dodecaherdron](http://rpgcharacters.wordpress.com/), where you can find hundreds of free maps, and few other great gaming ideas.

Personally, however, I would suggest that you do create the dungeons yourself. The task may seem a bit daunting, but it is a lot easier than it sounds, and you will get a lot more out of it.

Comment: Curious about what the suggested benefits of self-made dungeons are - but that doesn't belong in comments. Not sure how to create a chatroom for us to discuss this, if you feel like it. If you see me around in RPG General, I'd be curious to hear more. :)

Comment: @Julix The primary benefit is that a homemade dungeon has more flexibility. Whenever I begin a dungeon for my friends, it never ends the way it started. However, it is also a lot easier to build a storyline around the dungeons you build yourself, and to follow it.              A dungeon you made yourself is closer to you and your players, a premade dungeon is a little distant.